# Is it possible to use isalpha() on a math string, and still return True in python?

Tags: python, string

For example, I want to return True if the string is **all lowercase**, and only contains **alphabetical characters (with the exception of math operators)**.

For example:
`'x'` is True, `'X'` is False, `'x+y'` is True `# here's where it doesn't work`.

My current condition is:

```
if not str.islower() or not str.isalpha():
    return False
```

When I do `x+y`, it is all `lower`, but the string is not `alpha`. I want a way to somehow `ignore` the standard math operators: `+, -, *` since this **is** a **math expression**. Is this possible without much code?

Comment: You need to add an additional condition somewhere: `any(char in str for char in "+-*")`.

Comment: I don't really know compressed for loops, can you expand it?

Comment: If you mean "list comprehension", then why don't you read about it? OP is not a tutoring site.

Comment: Have you considered a regular expression?  Something like `[a-z*/+-]*` should do what you're looking for?

Comment: @DYZ, I know, I just hoped you could write it out the proper way instead of compressing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] I want to return True if the string is all lowercase, and only contains alphabetical characters (with the exception of math operators).

In my opinion the simplest solution would simply be to make your own function:

```
def is_valid_string(string, operators):
    string = ''.join([c for c in string if c not in operators])
    return all(c.isalpha() and c.lower() for c in string)
```

And it could be used like so:

```
if is_valid_string(str):
    # code
```

In this way, you can easily customize which operators are ignored and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re
return bool(re.fullmatch(r'[a-z*/+-]+', 'x+y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and turn your code to:

```
import re
p = re.compile('^[a-z+*/-]+$')
return p.match(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
comp = string.ascii_lowercase + "+-/*"
```

Then your valid replacement is:

```
if not all([False for char in str if char not in comp]):
    return False
```

Uses a set `in` for each char, and only builds a list on failures (fast for good matches).

As a function:

```
def valid(string):
    comp = string.ascii_lowercase + "+-/*"
    return all([False for char in str if char not in comp])
```